# start project after cloning ng-boilerplate

Tags: angularjs, ngboilerplate

I'm starting with angular.js and after reading realized that I should use ng-boilerplate to bootstrap my project. But I'm a bit confused, I've cloned the project and stuff and I have a project called ng-boilerplate with all the structure needed, but what now? Do I need to change the project name "ng-boilerplate" to my project name? And what about the folders for example "Home" and "About"? Do I need to delete these folders and create the ones I need? I guess I have to remove some code in other files right? the problem is that I'm starting with angular so don't know what should I remove and what not.
As you can see I'm pretty new with this, am I right with the procedure?
thanks

Comment: Why not you are trying https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you read the ngboilerplate documentation carefully you will understand it use. As the first line says:

> ngBoilerplate is designed to make life easy by providing a basic
>   framework with which to kickstart AngularJS projects.

`ngboilerplate` like many other seed projects, provide a prescriptive guideline about how a project should be structured. To demonstrate the working of the setup some project like this one add implementation for some standard scenarios to highlight how the complete setup works. Remember a working sample is far better than writing lengthy documentation.

The pages that you have mentioned are indeed for demo purpose and you can remove the folders if required. What this organization is telling us is that group your model-view-controller implementation  together into a folder. These folders could be one per view or one per feature. The documentation on the site itself is self explanatory here https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.2-release/src/app

Almost all folders of `ngboilerplate` have some documentation around specifics of that area. Read it to learn more about it.